# How to prevent the users from paying failed invoice in the Stripe customer portal

Tags: stripe-payments

I use Stripe subscriptions and I configured the retry mechanism for failed payment, so I don't really see a reason to allow the customer to manually pay a failed invoice in the customer portal.

I saw there's an option to disable the Invoice History which would effectivement prevent that, but I'd like to keep this history.

So, is there a way to prevent the customers to manually pay an invoice in the Stripe Customer Portal?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can filter which open Invoices show up in the history. Is there a specific reason that you want to prevent your users from being able to input new payment method data if other payments failed? Stripe's retry logic will stop if a payment is made successfully that way so the user should not be in danger of being double-charged.

Comment: I don't want to prevent adding a new payment method, I want to prevent manually paying a previous invoice.
The reason for that is that the user could pay an invoice that is many months old and not benefit from the service since Stripe won't adjust the subscription current end period.

Comment: Are you expecting to ever take payment on those months old invoices? If not, it may be appropriate to void them which would close the Invoice and prevent the user from paying it in the future. Does that sound appropriate for your situation? https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/overview#void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not expecting to take payment on these Invoices in future, you can void them. Voiding an Invoice will close it and prevent the user from paying it in future.

https://stripe.com/docs/invoicing/overview#void

Comment: I see there's a way to automatically mark invoices as uncollectible when all retries fail. Is there a similar setting to mark them as void instead?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment. To get similar behavior, you may want to set that behavior to mark them as uncollectible, listen for the `invoice.marked_uncollectible` event, and make the void invoice whenever you get that event.